# I have error in simple spring jdbc application

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4413ee:
>   startup date [Fri Jun 26 16:02:03 CDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
>   Implementing class

I have connection with sql table. I have include all jars that is required. I have no idea what to do with it. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi all, I have solved the problem. The solution is that I have two versions of the same library in your tomcat server.

Comment: you can post it as an answer and accept it to imply that it has been solved.
+1 for not waiting for an answer and solving it yourself. keep it up!

Comment: How can accept it to imply for my question?